# Python beautifulsoup not grabbing full table

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I'm not sure if this is not grabbing the full table because of `mechanize`

This works:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = 'http://www.airchina.com.cn/www/jsp/airlines_operating_data/exlshow_en.jsp'
r = requests.get(page)

r.encoding = 'utf-8'
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)

div = soup.find('div', class_='mainRight').find_all('div')[1]
table = div.find('table', recursive=False)

for row in table.find_all('tr', recursive=False):
    for cell in row('td', recursive=False):
        print cell.text.split()
```

but this doesn't:

```
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL='http://www.airchina.com.cn/www/jsp/airlines_operating_data/exlshow_en.jsp'
control_year=['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014']
control_month=['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12']

br = mechanize.Browser()
r=br.open(URL)

br.select_form("exl")
control_m = br.form.find_control('month')
control_y = br.form.find_control('year')

br[control_m.name]=['06'] 
br[control_y.name]=['2012']
response = br.submit()
soup = BeautifulSoup(response,'html.parser')
#div = soup.find('div', class_='mainRight')


div = soup.find('div', class_='mainRight').find_all('div')[1]
table = div.find('table', recursive=False)
for row in table.find_all('tr', recursive=False):
    for cell in row('td', recursive=False):
        print cell.text.strip()
```

The one that uses `mechanize` only produces the below, even though in firebug i see all of the `tr` and `td`

```
Jun 2012
% change vs Jun 2011
% change vs May 2012
Cumulative Jun 2012
% cumulative change
```

Comment: Odds are it is automatically adding `tbody` elements inside of the table. Try looping through all `tbody` within `table` before the `tr`.

Comment: @Wolph. I tried `table.find_all('tbody')` but returns `[]`

Comment: I believe it might be related to the `html.parser` you're using, see my answer for a working version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When combining the two it works without a problem so it might be related to the `html.parser` you are using.

```
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = ('http://www.airchina.com.cn/www/jsp/airlines_operating_data/'
       'exlshow_en.jsp')
control_year = ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013',
                '2014']
control_month = ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10',
                 '11', '12']

br = mechanize.Browser()
r = br.open(URL)

br.select_form("exl")
control_m = br.form.find_control('month')
control_y = br.form.find_control('year')

br[control_m.name] = ['06']
br[control_y.name] = ['2012']
response = br.submit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(response)

div = soup.find('div', class_='mainRight').find_all('div')[1]
table = div.find('table', recursive=False)

for row in table.find_all('tr', recursive=False):
    for cell in row('td', recursive=False):
        print cell.text.split()
```

Comment: That worked! thanks for the help. I would have never thought of that.

Comment: I don't understand the `html.parser`. Sometimes it is the only thing that works. Sometimes it doesn't work.

Comment: The `html.parser` is the parser that's part of the Python distribution so it's always available. But it's not really the best you can get. `lxml` is much faster and very effective but it's a separate dependency meaning you'll need to install it yourself. You can find a list of parsers here: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser